# coalesce count equals 0 group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good evening! How do I `COALESCE` a grouped by `COUNT(*)` query?

```
SELECT categories.name, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) as total FROM questions
  INNER JOIN categories
    ON questions.categoryid = categories.categoryid
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

I read the docs and this is the main solution to do it, but it is not returning the categories with `total = 0`.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the return of `count()` cant be null, so you don't need to `coalesce` it

you probably try to get this?

```
SELECT categories.name, COUNT(questions.categoryid) as total 
FROM questions
RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories
    ON questions.categoryid = categories.categoryid
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: I want to return the categories with `count = 0` . That way it only selects the categories with >0 categories and their total.

Comment: The right join prints everything but instead of a 0, got a 1.

Comment: sure - my pleasure